# How to call method of COM in parallel

Tags: multithreading, com

Now, I've developed an ATL that compiled with _ATL_MULTI_THREADED.
The COM dll was called in my C# winform appliaction. 
The COM interface look like this:(in c#)

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType=MethodCodeType.Runtime), 
    void RunFunction();
}
```

In my C# application:
  I created two threads that named TA,and TB.
  In both the thread function body, I invoke the `IMyInterface.RunFunction` method in parallel.

But, the codes in `IMyInterface` run another thread.(not TA or TB)

If there is some setting to force the COM code runs in the client's thread???

Comment: Understand hot it works [Understanding and Using COM Threading Models](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809971.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your winforms thread is STA which means that all calls, regardless of thread, to com objects created in the winform thread will use the winform thread. Create the com object in TA or TB

Comment: I try to modify the main form thread mode from   [STAThread] to [MTAThread]. But, lots of code will be crashed for COM reason. Therefore, just use the "Apartment Thread" mode of COM.

Comment: You can't change the threading model of winforms. If you want the com object to use a another thread you must create it in the another thread. If that thread is MTA you can then use the com object from other MTA threads without a thread switch.